# fileuploadsize for image and video at one submit does not work well

Tags: php, html

i try such a long time to find out how to solve my problem for this. I want to upload an Image and an video file over submit function for different size. Image has to be ~1MB and the videofile ~10MB. Also I dont realize how i can stop the part of the code to throw just the error message out without the rest. Have someone an better idea how i can write that code? ty .Here is my Code:

```
...//Part of code

    <th class="box-cv-" colspan="2" align="center">
    Bild upload(max.1MB):<br>
            <input type="file" name="uploaddatei" size="10" accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/gif" maxlength="250"><br>
    </th>
    <th class="box-cv-" colspan="2" align="center">
    Video upload(max.10MB):<br>
            <input type="file" name="uploaddatei2" size="10" accept="video/mp4" maxlength="250">
    </th>

..//Part of Code 

if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name']  < 1000000 ) {
  $zugelassenedateitypen = array("image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif");
  if ( ! in_array( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['type'] , $zugelassenedateitypen )) {
    echo "<p>Dateitype ist NICHT zugelassen</p>";
  }
  if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] > 1000000) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    echo "<p>Bilddatei Datei zu groß!</p>";
  }
  else {
    $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] = dateiname_bereinigen($_FILES['uploaddatei']['name']);
    if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] < 1000000 ) {
      move_uploaded_file (
      $_FILES['uploaddatei']['tmp_name'] ,
      '../../../images/'. $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] );
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>Dateiname ist nicht zulässig</p>";
    }
  }
}
//Same shit for the Video file 
if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name']  < 10000000 ) {
...
}

function dateiname_bereinigen($dateiname) { 
...//Part for the name 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name']  <> "" ) {
    $zugelassenedateitypen = array("image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif");
    if ( ! in_array( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['type'] , $zugelassenedateitypen )) {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$err[8][0]["Beschreibung"] . $err[7][0]["Beschreibung"].'")</script>';
    }
    if($_FILES['uploaddatei']['size'] > 1000000) {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$err[9][0]["Beschreibung"] . $err[7][0]["Beschreibung"].'")</script>';
    }
    else {
         // Test ob Dateiname in Ordnung
         $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] = dateiname_bereinigen($_FILES['uploaddatei']['name']);
         if ( $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] <> '' ) {
             move_uploaded_file (
             $_FILES['uploaddatei']['tmp_name'] , '../../../images/projekt_lebenslauf/'. $_FILES['uploaddatei']['name'] );
         }
    }
}
```

It works for me =)